# Point EC2 public IP address to subdomain

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, dns, ip, amazon-route53

I want to point a subdomain to an EC2 and I don't want to use Elastic IP and every time I start/stop the instance I want my subdomain point to the new Instance public IP address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest method is to use an **Elastic IP address**. It will remain attached to the instance and will not change. There is no additional charge for an Elastic IP address if it is attached to a running instance.

Alternatively, you could configure the operating system running on the instance to run a script whenever the instance starts. The script can **update the DNS entry for the current public IP address associated with the instance**. If you are using Amazon Route 53 for DNS, then you can make an API call that updates the A-Record to the current IP address being used by the instance.

I suspect it could be done with the [change-resource-record-sets](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/route53/change-resource-record-sets.html) command in the AWS CLI.